# Custom arabic numbering in appendix does not appear at the last page of appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I am writing a document which inherits koma-script. I want different page-numbering in appendix, but for the last page in appendix it doesn't appear as formatted.

```
\documentclass[%
english,
cdfont=false,
cdtitle=color,
cdfont=nodin
]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}

  \tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  %%%%%%% RESETTING PAGE NUMBERING TO 1.
\chapter{Requirement/Limitation}
\section{Layout Dependancy}
\section{corner Dependancy}
\chapter{Performance on a Large Design}
\section{Design}
\section{Results}
\chapter{Future Works}


\begin{appendices}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
\chapter{Parasitic Extraction}
\chapter{Development of Box Methodology}
\blindtext
\end{appendices}
\newpage

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
% \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why doesn't the page number for appendix B appear as B-1?

Comment: Unfortunately your example code is not working and does not result in the image. We do neither have `Chapters/1_introduction` nor does any shown package or the class define an environment `appendices`. Please always try to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that can be used to reproduce the problem. We also need such a MWE to test our suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\end{appendices}` finishes the scope of your `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}` before you output the page using `\newpage`. So you have to move `\newpage` before `\end{appendices}`:

```
\begin{appendices}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
% First end the page …
\newpage
% … then the environment
\end{appendices}
```

I've not added a working example, because the example code of the question is also not a working example.